# What do we know about Embedding problem of Covering spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, reference-request, differential-topology, geometric-topology

My question might be broad. Let $E$ be the covering space of $B$, what do we know about the embedding of $E$ (into some space)? I am looking for some general results or references.

EDIT: After Lee Mosher's comment:

I could make it bit specific, for example, if the space $B$ admits triangulation or is a compact n-manifold. What can we say about the embedding of $E$. I found the following result [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32111/compactness-and-covering-spaces)

> If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an $r$-sheeted covering space with $X$ being a compact topological space, then $Y$ embedds in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$ for some natural $k$.

The proof follows from Whitney embedding theorem since by above link, $Y$ is compact.

Though I wanted some general results, my specific problem is for the space $B$ admitting triangulation.

Comment: Your question is indeed too broad. Every space $E$ is a covering space of something (itself, for example). So, this problem is no different from the problem of how to embed a general space into some other space.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I edited a question. Looking for triangulable spaces.

Comment: [That link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32111/compactness-and-covering-spaces) contains no result with the conclusion you state.

Comment: Yes, that link only says that $Y$ is compact but by Whitney embd. theo. , $Y$ can be embedded in some Euclidean space. I have changed the statement because of Whitney.

Comment: All forms of Whitney's theorem work regardless of compactness of the manifold you are embedding. (One can even get proper embeddings if needed.) I am sure it is in http://www.calvin.edu/~venema/embeddingsbook/embeddings-noprint.pdf